# VBA Unfilter range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using this code:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").AutofilterMode = False
```

to unfilter the data in an Excel sheet using VBA (the point is to clear all the filters). This doesn't seem to always work, is there a better way?

Thank you!

In case it helps, this table is linked from Sql Server (Data --> From other sources --> From Sql Server...) and it has a coloured design layout (table specific).

Comment: I found this works: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_Sam_table1").Range.AutoFilter Field :=2` but I need it to be general and work for all fields, not to clear just the second field filter, but all. Also, the solution stated in the initial question probably works only for isolated text, doesn't apply to objects (tables that have table names in their properties, etc).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData` instead. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178108%28v=office.12%29.aspx.

Answer (score 3):

The `ShowAllData` will work only if your sheet has a filter, otherwise it will break. I found that you can create a function from this with `On Error Resume Next` and it should work in all cases:

```
Sub ShowAllData()
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData

End Sub
```

Then call function from your main sub:

```
Sub Main()

ShowAllData

End Sub
```