# What is the correct vba to unfilter all columns in a table in excel and keep the filters in the column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table full of data that I have a drop down list that when you select the drop down item it filters the column in a table.

The problem I have is I want to have a simple reset button to unfilter the column. It's as simple as that. I don't want the filters to disappear though.

I have tried a boat load of solutions

For reference I used another submission to this site which did not work I got a "400" error message
[VBA Unfilter range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426837/vba-unfilter-range)

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

Another solution I tried

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    .Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    .AutoFilterMode = True
End With
```

There has to be something super simple I'm not accouting for here.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData` should work on a sheet containing a filter.  I've tried a few instances that would make it fail, but I don't get error 400 (Application-defined or object-defined error).  `ShowAllData` on a sheet with no filter or locked so you can't filter returns error `1004`.  Filtering on a non-existent sheet returns error `9`.  Can you manually clear the filter on the Data ribbon?

Comment: Yes, I can manually clear it. I'm just anticipating the customer wanting to be lazy and I'm trying to make it a simple click of the button to unfilter. I even tried recording a macro of unfiltering a column just to test it out on 1 column and that didn't work either.

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't.  Your code will work on the currently active workbook, but that returns the same errors as my first comment.  Was thinking maybe it mucks up with filters on a pivot table but clears them to.  Is it that exact line that the error occurs on?  Asking as I can't get it to throw error 400.

Comment: This is so confusing. I have no idea why this isnt' working other than the fact that the filtered range is in a table. But I haven't seen any examples online that have different vba because of the data filters filtering a table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. I'm not sure of the exact science behind it but the range of the table has to be selected before anything.

```
    Sub Unfilter()
'Unfilter all table columns
     ActiveSheet.Range("R15:BH1072").Select
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode = True Then
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you are using a TABLE instead of a RANGE you will have to corretcly reference the table because it belongs to a different object collection:

Using a table: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table288").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1`

Using a range: just the range: `ActiveSheet.Range("$P$6:$R$10").AutoFilter Field:=1`

Note: I used this via Macro recorder to to show the example, your code should be tweaked to fit your needs.